# CPPFLAGS equivalent in Xcode project

Tags: xcode, gcc, makefile, build-process

So I'm trying to port a make file to Xcode. Not sure where to put stuff from `CPPFLAGS`.
Currently `CPPFLAGS = -I../src/` meaning that the preprocessor will append ../src/ to the include directives while trying to resolve paths. I can not modify the source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any explicit `-I` switches if you put all your source files and headers into the Xcode project. Xcode will generate all the necessary include directives at build time as it knows where all the headers are.

Comment: I have added ../src/ (without -I) to the Header Search Paths of the Build Settings and it worked.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this unless for some reason you haven't included the relevant directories in the project itself. Although both methods work as far as compiling is concerned, it's usually preferable to do it the way I suggested above as this helps with navigation, debugging, looking up symbols, etc.